# Azure event grid to check

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I have a requirement to move a file from ADLS Gen 2 from path(directory) 'A' to directory 'B' or 'C' based on 2 conditions : Move to 'C' if file is not csv or file size is 0 else move to 'B'.

I am planning to use Event grid (as soon as file lands in location 'A')+ Azure function (for checks and move to location 'B' or 'C').

If there are 100 files landing per day, this approach will trigger azure function 100 times.

Is there a better way to do this - can this smarts be built using just one service (such as Event Hub instead of Event grid + Function) so that there is less overhead to maintain.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want low effort then try Logic Apps.

What you want is to create a [Logic App with Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage), that will be triggered when there are new blobs. That takes care of trigger.

[For action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-action), you can use the "copy blob" if you like. Not sure if there is a "move blob" action supported, but if it's not and "copy blob" action isn't good enough for you then you can provide a custom [JS snippet action as inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code).

Couple of notes:

- If your Azure Functions are called only 100 times a day and they are only doing some small check and then moving the blob, then under consumption plan you'll probably pay less than a $1 US per month.
- With Azure Functions you'll have a lot more control and it'll take you a lot longer (compared to Logic Apps) to develop/operate.

Answer (score 1):

> can this smarts be built using just one service

Of course, you can directly use blob trigger of azure function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp

> If there are 100 files landing per day, this approach will trigger
> azure function 100 times.

You can use azure function to do a daily check instead of use event grid to trigger function(Timertrigger).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

Just put the logic in the body of function.